# Omx bad parameter error from mediac codec encoder

Tags: android

I am using the media codec API for encoding on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 which has OMAP 4430 and I get OMX bad parameter error .

So I have few parameter access from the application side , width, height, bitrate, framerate, I-frame interval.  And I am setting this below values to create AVC encoder :

Bitrate = 125000 , Ht : 640 , Wd : 360 , I -frame interval : 1 , frame rate : 25fps.

So looking to it all the parameters seems to be reasonable but still it throws OMX Bad parameter error.

Comment: What about the color format?

Comment: Color format YUV420SP, this is the one it only supports for any other format it throws error